# Django-paypal ipn notify_url not responding

Tags: django, python-2.7, paypal-ipn, django-paypal

My `settings.py` is:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
.......,
'paypal.standard.ipn',
)

PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL = "coolakashsaikia-facilitator@gmail.com"
PAYPAL_TEST = True
```

My `views.py` is:

```
@csrf_exempt
def pricing(request):
  paypal_dict_flexible = {
     "business": "coolakashsaikia-facilitator@gmail.com",
     "amount": "100.00",
     "item_name": "Flexible Subscription",
     "invoice": "10",
     "notify_url": "https://example.com/notify",
     "return_url": "http://example.com/signup",
     "cancel_return": "",
 }

 form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict_flexible)
 context = {"form": form, 'current_page': 'pricing'}
 return render_to_response("leavebuddyapp/pricing.html", context)

 @csrf_exempt
 def notify(request):
     return HttpResponse("Notify called")
```

My `urls.py` is:

```
 urlpatterns = patterns('',
   #Paypal
   (r'^notify', include('paypal.standard.ipn.urls')),

 )
```

My template is:

```
 <div class="test">
       {{ form.render }}
       <a href="/signup/flexible" class="btn">Buy now</a>
  </div>
```

My problem is that the function "`notify`" in the `views.py` is not being called. Can you guys please guide me into the right direction. I am not getting what I am doing wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation, you have correctly added following line in urls.py

```
(r'^notify', include('paypal.standard.ipn.urls')),
```

Above code snippets means that `https://example.com/notify` url directly call the paypal pacakge views ipn funcation, which is actually designed for handling the ipn response.

So @Shivratna you don't need to implement any other `notify` function in your views.

Can you make sure following things are done, before you do the paypal transaction:

1. notify url correct in your sandbox or live paypal account settings
2. as well as in the config dict `like paypal_dict_flexible`
3. assuming you have installed package properly, but don't forgot to run `python manage.py syncdb` which creates tables for django-paypal package

I hope my suggestion will show you right direction  ;)

Comment: @Shivratna, What you did please let me know, I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you think that the `/notify` url should call your view. Your url configuration points your `/notify` url to the `paypal.standard.ipn.views.ipn` view by including the paypal url configuration.

If you want to call your `notify` view, you should include it in your url configuration:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    (r'^notify/$', myapp.views.notify),
)
```

However, I highly doubt you'd want to write your own view for the paypal ipn callback. Django-paypal's default ipn view includes signal hooks where you can easily add your own custom logic.

Comment: Thank you so much....my bad, i had fegured it out, but now when the default ipn view is called, i get 500 error. Any idea why this would be happening...?

Comment: @Shivratna Lots of reasons. Post a new question with some more information, like debugging logs/traceback.